# Creating custom color ramp using "r.colors" GRASS GIS function

Tags: grass-gis, color-ramp, gmt

I am trying to assign a raster/grid a custom color palette in GRASS using the "r.colors" function.

```
r.colors map=Consensus_BRT_RCP85 colors=rules
```

This allows me to input my rules for my color palette:

```
0 238:238:238
0.06 0:0:255
0.33 0:255:255
0.67 255:255:0
1.0 255:0:0 
end
```

This function operates, but it doesn't create the color palette I would like. [image]

I'd like it to be like my custom GMT color palette:

```
0.000000 238 238 238 0.060000 238 238 238
0.060000   0   0 255 0.333333   0   0 255
0.333333   0 255 255 0.666667 255 255   0
0.666667 255 255   0 1.000000 255   0   0
```

My GMT palette looks like this (I want my probabilistic map to have this color ramp):[image]

I've seen that there is a function called "r.cpt2grass" but this function isn't found on my GRASS installation (not sure what to do about GRASS GIS "add-ons").

Answer (score 2):

A way to do this is with a "reclass" map, set up to classify the continuous data into fixed categories. The format of the reclass file might be:

```
GRASS 7.0.0 (WGS84):~ >cat concensus_reclass.txt
0.000000 thru 0.059999 = 1
0.060000 thru 0.333332 = 2
0.333333 thru 0.666666 = 3
0.666667 thru 1.0 = 4
```

Your color rules file will be changed to:

```
1 238:238:238
2 0:0:255
3 0:255:255
4 255:255:0
default 255:0:0
```

Now you run:

```
GRASS 7.0.0 (WGS84):~ >r.reclass input=Consensus_BRT_RCP85 output=Consensus_BRT_RCP85_reclass rules=concensus_reclass.txt
GRASS 7.0.0 (WGS84):~ >r.colors Consensus_BRT_RCP85_reclass rules=new_rules.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

As you say, [r.cpt2grass](http://grass.fsv.cvut.cz/wiki-mirror/index.php/GRASS_AddOns#r.cpt2grass) is an add-on. Simply download the script and make it executable. It should be executed in the Grass environment (GRASS shell for example)

```
GRASS 6.4.4 (geol):~ > r.cpt2grass --help # or GRASS 7
Description:
Convert or apply a GMT color table to a GRASS raster map
Usage:
r.cpt2grass [-s] input=string [map=string] [output=string]
[--verbose] [--quiet]
Flags:
-s   Stretch color scale to match map data extent
--v   Verbose module output
--q   Quiet module output
Parameters:
 input   Name of input GMT color table (.cpt file)
 map   Raster map to apply it to
 output   Name for new rules file, or "-" for stdout
```

Therefore with your original palette (named your.cpt here):

```
# COLOR_MODEL = RGB
0.000000 238 238 238 0.060000 238 238 238
0.060000   0   0 255 0.333333   0   0 255
0.333333   0 255 255 0.666667 255 255   0
0.666667 255 255   0 1.000000 255   0   0
```

Simple conversion (without applying to a particular raster)

```
GRASS 6.4.4 (geol):~ > r.cpt2grass input=your.cpt  output=your
```

And the result

```
# GMT color map created with r.cpt2grass
#  from [/Users/Shared/your.cpt]...
# COLOR_MODEL = RGB
0.000000 238:238:238
0.060000 238:238:238
0.060000 0:0:255
0.333333 0:0:255
0.333333 0:255:255
0.666667 255:255:0
1.000000 255:0:0
```

But I don't know if it works (it is and old script,2007), especially if you want to apply the resulting table to a particular raster.

```
 ERROR: bad rule (percentage not in range 0-100): [125% 20:20:20]
```

Note that most of the original GMT palettes have been integrated into GRASS GIS.

Answer (score 1):

@Micha's and @gene's answers were helpful for me to get to my desired results.

```
GRASS 6.4.4 (my_project) :~ sudo vim $GISBASE/etc/colors bcyr_custom.txt
```

(enter my password). Now I slightly change the "bcyr" color palette.

```
-0.000001 255:255:255
 0.000000 255:255:255
 0.060000 255:255:255
 0.060001 blue
 0.333333 cyan
 0.666667 yellow
 1.000000 red
 default 255:0:0
```

Apply my custom color palette.

```
r.colors map=Consensus_BRT_RCP85 color=bcyr_custom.txt
d.mon start=x0
d.rast Consensus_BRT_RCP85
```

My map.
[image]